# Why this nullpointerexception keeps on coming? I have written the error in the end. I have also mentioned the line where the error occurs

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, nullpointerexception, getter

Null Pointer Exception Occurs while calling getter function.  Please help as fast as possible.  I have written the error in the end. I have also mentioned the line where the error occurs. Partial output is correct though.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        /* Do not alter code in main method */
         Shirt[] shirts = new Shirt[5];

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
         {
            int tag = sc.nextInt();sc.nextLine();
            String brand = sc.nextLine();
            double price = sc.nextDouble();sc.nextLine();
            char g = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
            shirts[i] = new Shirt(tag,brand,price,g);
         }
         double price = sc.nextDouble();
         for(Shirt s: shirts)
         {
              System.out.println(getDiscountPrice(s));            
         }
         Shirt[] result = getShirtWithMoreThanSpecificPrice(shirts,price);
         for(Shirt s: result)
         {
             System.out.println(s.getTag()+" "+s.getPrice()+" "+s.getBrand());//This is where the exception occurs
         }
    }
    public static double getDiscountPrice(Shirt s)
    {
        double p;
        if(s.g=='m')
        {
            p=s.price-((0.1*s.price));
            return p;
        }
        if(s.g=='f')
        {
            p=s.price-((0.2*s.price));
            return p;
        }
        if(s.g=='u')
        {
            p=s.price-((0.3*s.price));
            return p;
        }
            return 0.0;
    }
    public static Shirt[] getShirtWithMoreThanSpecificPrice(Shirt[] shirts,double price)
   {
        Shirt[] sh=new Shirt[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(shirts[i].price>price)
            {
                sh[i]=shirts[i];
            }
        }
        return sh;
  }
  }
 class Shirt
 {
    //define the class as per details shared in the question
    int tag;
    String brand; 
    double price;
    char g;
    public Shirt(int tag,String brand,double price,char g)
    {
    this.brand=brand;
    this.g=g;
    this.price=price;
    this.tag=tag;
    }
    public void setG(char g) 
    {
    this.g = g;
    }
    public void setTag(int tag) 
    {
    this.tag = tag;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) 
    {
    this.brand = brand;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) 
    {
    this.price = price;
    }
    public int getTag() 
    {
    return tag;
    }
    public double getPrice() 
    {
    return price;
    }
    public String getBrand() 
    {
    return brand;
    }
     public char getG() 
    {
    return g;
    }
}
```

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Solution.main(Solution.java:32

Error occurs at line no 32. I tried to initialize the variables. None of it was successful.

Comment: Which line of the code is line 32, please? Counting lines in code posted here on SO is shaky at best, so you’d better point it out for us. Edit your question and either put an appropriate comment after line 32 or quote that line again after the error.

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate a new array in `getShirtWithMoreThanSpecificPrice` with `Shirt[] sh = new Shirt[5]`, it's initialized with five `null` values.

Then you assign elements, but only conditionally: `if (shirts[i].price > price) sh[i] = shirts[i];`. Hence some value may still be `null`. When you loop on this array in `main`, you must check in `for (Shirt s: result)` whether `s` is `null` or not. It can happen, and it's what happened here.

Now, it may be preferable to return an array with only the non-null values, that is, those shirts for which `shirts[i].price > price`. You may use a `List` instead (append only non-null values) or `Arrays.copyOf` (if you manage to store non-null values at the beginning of the array `sh`, without holes).

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your for loop code with this:

```
for (Shirt s : result) {
    if(s != null) {
        System.out.println(s.getTag() + " " + s.getPrice() + " " + s.getBrand());// This is where the exception
    }
                                                                                        // occurs
}
```

As you are initializing your array without assigning values, it is having default values as `null`.